# react-native-svg "rect" height: 100% not filling screen

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-svg

Cannot get `Rect` to fill screen.

Example Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/7hfIOdDDX

Demo Code:

```js
<View style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}>
  <Svg height="100%" width="100%" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <Rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />
  </Svg>
</View>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I get it to fill the whole screen height?

Comment: please try this_ `<svg height="100vh" width="100vw" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 100 100">`

Comment: `preserveAspectRatio="none"` does fill the screen but it stretches the svg, in react-native "100vh" and "100vw" are not supported, is there a way fill the screen without stretching?

Comment: How do you want something that's 100 x 100 to fill a screen that doesn't have a 1:1 aspect ratio without stretching i.e. what do you want it to look like? You want it to overflow at the sides?

Comment: @RobertLongson makes sense, I removed "viewBox" now it fills the screen, but when screen rotates it doesn't update the height and width.

Comment: Try `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"` This won't stretch but will slice the overflow